# Pass a property value from pop up window to parent window : javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a parent window with a button, on click of this button i am storing page content into a object. At the same time i am opening a pop window which has radio button and a save button. After clicking on any of the radio button and hitting save. I like to send the value of radio button into the parent page. Please go through code snippet.

```
function onclickParentButton(){
    var var1 = document.getElementById("id1");
    var parentRequest = new Object();
    parentRequest.prop1 = var1;
    window.open("popPage.jsp");
}
/* onclick of save button in pop up window*/
function onClickSaveBtnPopUp(){
    var radioBtnVal = $("input:radio[name='radioBtnVal']:checked").val();   
    // close pop up and return radioBtnVal to parent page
    return radioBtnVal;
}
```

I want to have this radioBtnVal available in the Parent Page

Comment: Assuming all come from the same server, have a function in the parent and call it from the popup page `opener.savePopupButton("somevalue")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
function onClickSaveBtnPopUp(){
    var radioBtnVal = $("input:radio[name='radioBtnVal']:checked", opener.window.document).val();   
}
```

Using opener.window.document you can access parent window element...

Comment: opener.window is just opener, but does $() take a DOM object as a second parameter?

Comment: Yes, you can also use `$('#MyIDName', window.parent.document).html();` To access parent window element.

Comment: window.parent and parent are the same. parent, opener, top are all windows

Comment: I want to handover the control all over again to parent window closing the pop up, and  returning the radioBtnVal as well to the parent window.